# Solution for a Fokker-Planck type PDE

Tags: probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations

I have a Fokker-Planck type equation for probability $p(x, t)$
$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2} + \left( k - \frac{c}{x} \right) \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} + \frac{c}{x^2} p $$
with real positive constants $k$ and $c$. Additionally, $x$ is taken to be positive.
The equation can also be written more compactly as
$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} + \left( k - \frac{c}{x} \right) p \right] .$$
I'm interested naturally in the solution of this equation but also in any resources related to this type (I don't know which type this is) of equation.

I tried a separation of variables approach $p(x, t) = \Phi(x) \Psi(t)$
$$ \Phi \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} = \left[ \frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial x^2} + \left( k - \frac{c}{x} \right) \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} + \frac{c}{x^2} \Phi \right] \Psi $$
which I think suggests an exponential form $\Psi = e^{-At}$. Then I would be left with
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial x^2} + \left( k - \frac{c}{x} \right) \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} + \left( \frac{c}{x^2} + A \right) \Phi = 0 .$$
I tried inputting this to WolframAlpha and it indeed gives a solution but it involves a confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind and an associated Laguerre polynomial
$$ \Phi = x^c e^{-kx} e^{\frac{x}{2} \left(k - \sqrt{k^2 - 4 A}\right)} \left(
a_1 U\left[ \frac{c}{2} \left( 1 - \frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2 - 4A}} \right), c, x \sqrt{k^2 - 4 A} \right]
+ a_2 L_{\frac{c}{2} \left( \frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2 - 4A}} - 1 \right)}^{c-1} \left( x \sqrt{k^2 - 4 A} \right)
\right) 
$$
which feels a bit overkill and not very easy to understand.

EDIT: The equation for $\Phi$ written as
$$ x^2 \frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial x^2} + x \left( k x - c \right) \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} + \left( c + A x^2 \right) \Phi = 0 $$
seems to be close to the Bessel equation
$$ x^2 \frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial x^2} + x \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} + \left( x^2 - \alpha^2 \right) \Phi = 0 $$

Comment: Have any interest in the behavior of individual sample paths? For example the solution to the SDE $dX_t = -(k-c/X_t) dt + \sqrt{2}dB_t$ has probability transition density $p(t,x)$ solving your PDE.

Comment: In [Sturm-Liouville form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory?useskin=vector) $(e^{kx}x^{-c}y')'+ce^{kx}x^{c-2}y=-\lambda e^{kx} x^{-c} y$, (where I write $y$ for $\Phi$ and $\lambda$ for $a$) we see the solutions will be orthogonal with weight $e^{kx}x^{-c}$. The steady state solution is $x^{c}e^{-kx}$. You need to use the boundary conditions to determine the relation between the constants you call $a_1$ and $a_2$, and the (presumed finite) behavior at $x\to\infty$ to find the appropriate $\lambda$. I think its something like $\lambda_n=\frac{k^2 n(n-c)}{(2n-c)^2}$

Comment: @NapD.Lover Thank you, this SDE was actually the starting point for me. I'm interested in getting some form of analytical solution to obtain the behavior for specific boundary conditions.

Comment: @Sal The Sturm-Liouville form seems helpful. Both of the solutions given by WolframAlpha have this $e^{\frac{x}{2} \left( k - \sqrt{k^2 - 4A} \right)}$ prefactor (there was a mistake in the solution of the original post, fixed now). This doesn't come out of the Sturm-Liouville form, any ideas on how one could obtain it?

Comment: To transform your equation into [Kummer's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function?useskin=vector), let $y(x)=x^\alpha g(x)$ then after substitution note that $\alpha=c$ produces an equation with linear in $x$ coefficients on each term. Then let $g(x)=e^{\beta x}h(x)$ and note that after substitution $2\beta=k\pm\sqrt{k^2-4\lambda}$ simplifies everything to $xh''+(B-x)h'+Ah=0$ for some constants $A$, $B$

Comment: @Sal Thank you very much, this has been really helpful. Does the $2 \beta = k + \sqrt{k^2 - 4 \lambda}$ run into some issues (as it is not included in the solution given by WolframAlpha)? It would make the $B$ in Kummer's equation to be negative.

Comment: The issue is when $k^2-4\lambda=0$ in which case one of the solutions needs to be modified. There is no issue in principle with $k^2-4\lambda<0$ yielding complex solutions, which you may still reject on physical grounds. Since this is a singular BVP, the results of regular Sturm Liouville theory need not all hold, and the general analysis of such problems can become quite intricate. In your case we have both linearly independent solutions $\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ which means it may be impossible to fix the boundary condition at $x=0$...

Comment: @655321 if you are still interested in an answer I can write one, as I just spent a little time studying singular ODEs

Comment: @Sal: Yes please, I think I have some form of solution but your input will most likely be valuable. I was also thinking that in the first separation of variables step, shouldn't $A$ be a function of $x$? I just assumed that equation of the form $\partial \Psi / \partial t = f(x) \Psi(t)$ should have a solution of form $\Psi = e^{-At}$.

Comment: After thinking for a second: $A$ needs to be a constant, but that implies that the $f(x)$ part is constant too, right?

Comment: @655321 okay will write some stuff today- your separation constant cant be a function of $x$, using the the separation of variables arguments

Comment: Using Weyl's classification, we can examine $N(a,b)=\int_a^b dx\ w(x)|y(x)|^2$ where $w(x)=e^{kx}x^{-c}$ is the weight function from Sturm-Lioville form. The point $0$ is a 'limit circle' as all solutions satisfy $N(0,b)\lt\infty$ for finite $b$ and *any* eigenvalue. The point $\infty$ is a 'limit point' and there is exactly one solution with finite $N(a,\infty)$. Usual specification of boundary values won't work for singular problems. See for eg [this review](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1034117) or [this book](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470906538)